# Organization of request parameters, header and variables in Postman request builder

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

Recently I started writing tests in Postman and would like to know good practices to do it.
I have many collections and many(even 25) requests in each collection.
I want to run these tests on different environments(DEV,SIT,UAT) and want to organize path, query parameters, header, body the best way.
I created environemnt variables for url, query and path parameters, header and used them in each collection and each request.
I thought if I change values in the request body into the environment variables I would be able to use the same json collection files for 3 environments and only change environment from the dropdown when switching between testing environemnts. But this would cause the environment variables difficult to maintenance.

Comment: Hi could you please add what is the maintenance headache you refer to ? Please add more details about the issue

Comment: if I move all the request body values into the environment variables then this file would grow dramatically. In some post request I have even 7 lines of key/value parameters. If I do that there will be even 50 rows for one collection, 300 rows for 6 colelctions in one environment variable file.
And I am not sure if changing request body values into
```{
"key1" : {{environmentVariable1}}
}```
is a good practice.   But besides this messy environment variable file I like this solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.